# Firefox general.useragent.override not working

Tags: javascript, firefox

to do some testings I have set the browser version for firefox by setting general.useragent.override="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)" but the browser is still identified as Netscape not as IE.

E.g. this JavaScript

```
console.log(navigator.appName);
```

still shows Netscape not IE as needed for the test. Any idea how to properely set the user agent in Firefox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

navigator.appName returns the string "Netscape" in all current browsers. navigator.userAgent will return the string you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunatetly the customer uses still IE 8 which has not much debugging capabilities. I would have to pretend beeing IE with my firefox if possible...!?

Comment: Even if you tell Firefox to pretend to be IE, it will still act like Firefox. If you can't use an actual copy of IE 8 I would suggest using IE 11, and using its Emulation settings in the F12 developer tools to set both the document mode and user agent string to IE 8.

Comment: thanks as IE 11 is not yet an option I hoped for some nice trick arround it at stackoverflow. will have to live with the old IE 8 debugging